# Bash pass parameters to function with single or double quotes

Tags: bash

I'm writing the following function:

```
add() 
{
    echo "$@"
    for item in "$@"; do
        case "$item" in 
            *=* ) echo "$item" ;;
        esac
    done
}
```

aiming to call `add first="first option" second="second"` and get:

```
first="first option"
second="second"
```

So, each parameter should be passed with spaces and quotes. However at the moment the function `echo` the following:

```
first=first
second=second
```

So, no quotes and the second word in `first` comes cut.
What am I missing?

My bash version
`GNU bash, version 5.0.11(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0)`.

### **SOLVED**

The code is correctly working, my terminal was set on another old bash version.

Comment: I have with bash 4.2.46 there is no quotes and no cut, both word `first option` on theirs place

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html#Double-Quotes):

> Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!’. The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘"’, ‘\’, or newline.

(just bracketing a string)

This way gives required result:

```sh
add "first=\"first option\"" "second=\"second\""
```

Comment: Hey thanks! It was my terminal not using the correct bash version...

Answer (score 1):

When I put following in test.sh

```
add() 
{
    echo "$@"
    for item in "$@"; do
        case "$item" in 
            *=* ) echo "$item" ;;
        esac
    done
}
add first="first option" second="second"
```

and run with

```
bash test.sh
```

I got

```
first=first option second=second
first=first option
second=second
```

Comment: damn! my terminal was reading bash 3.2.57